# Disparity Between Upvotes in Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion, etiquette, down-votes, up-votes

Should it ever be possible that a question and an answer have this much [disparity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866447/are-the-real-numbers-really-uncountable/866475#866475)? I don't understand how a question "is not good enough" to have positive net votes, but the answers to the question can have scores of 3,5,9 and 10.

---

Edited out part was a duplicate of [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10919/about-not-upvoted-answered-questions).

Comment: There even is a badge called [reversal](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/reversal) (questions -5 answer +20).

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: I have edited out the duplicate part of my question

Comment: Okay, I retracted the closevote. But with  one question left, numbering did not make much sense, so I reformatted.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: That's fine, thank you.

Comment: If you click the vote count (I'm not sure if you *can*, yet - I think that's at 1000 rep), it's at +5 / -5. So the question has been voted on quite a bit.

Comment: I’m ignorant about early August developments, but now all (IMHO) poorly considered or incompetent answers in the “uncountable” thread are now at 0, whereas the two most competent answers were at 10 when I came today. Is the problem defused?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: Yes! When you get to 1000 reputation, you will be able to see the upvotes and downvotes on the question. This question received +8 and -7. Some people really disliked the question for some reason or another. When I first stumbled upon the question, I thought it had received 1 upvote (my own) and maybe 1 downvote. I guess it was just very controversial.

Comment: @Kyle Gannon *numbers* of “+” and “−”, not *persons,* you mean? BTW, there is now some activity in the thread, but seemingly all I-do-not-likeists already expended their downvote at the question and can’t drag it down now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Votes are influenced by a number of factors. A common scenario: a question of poor quality suffers initial downvotes, then is brought into shape, but some of the downvotes remain, canceling with subsequent upvotes. Somewhat less common: a question is essentially a [lazy, vague  remark](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/539325/) which somehow gets an attractive answer (not necessarily a *great* answer, but something that many people find amusing enough to upvote). And sometimes the asker's attitude gets in the way of appreciating their question. Etc.

As T.Bongers said in a comment, the question to which you refer has $+5-5$ votes. When you reach 1000 reputation, you will be able to see the vote breakdown on each post. Meanwhile, you can see the chain of events, including voting, on the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/866447/timeline) of the question. There is no visible link to the timeline, so you'd have to either manifacture the URL, install a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/4148/), or (perhaps the easiest)  use [this bookmarklet](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC#timeline).

Comment: The answer in your referenced question provides some comic relief. Another amusing post is http://math.stackexchange.com/q/54506/27978.

Comment: Ah, I see. I get I just need to get more reputation then.